# Connected sum of arbitrary surface and two closed disks

Tags: general-topology

I just learned about connected sums and I am having difficulty visualizing the operation. If we have an arbitrary surface $S$  (A topological space that is locally homeomorphic to an open disk in the plane and Haussdorff) and we take its connected sum with a closed disk $\mathbb{\overline{D}}$, we obtain a surface with boundary $S^\prime = S  \# \mathbb{\overline{D}}$. Furthermore, say we glue $S^\prime$ and another disk $\mathbb{\overline{D}}$ together along their circle boundaries.

Questions:

What do we get after gluing $S^\prime$ to $\mathbb{\overline{D}}?$

How else can we describe the effect of taking the connected sum of a surface $S$ with $\mathbb{\overline{D}}?$

Comment: You may do the other way round: 

First glue to $\overline {\mathbb D}$ another disk $\overline {\mathbb D}$ along their boundary first. This forms a $2$-sphere $\mathbb S^2$. Then we take the connected sum of this $2$ sphere with $S$. Observe that $S \# \mathbb S^2$ is homeomorphic to $S$.

Comment: So after gluing $S^\prime$ to the closed disk $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, we just get $S$ back?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Note that when you got $S'$, all you really did was delete the interior of a closed disc.